# Xcodebuild: PhaseScriptExecution causes massive setenv flood in log

Tags: bash, jenkins, xcodebuild

On my Jenkins CI server I have a job that builds a project with a custom build rule to compress certain files. Every time this script is executed (on each single file of that type),  Xcodebuild logs setenv messages and therefore floods my console with redundant information. How can I avoid those messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to untick the box "Show environment variables in build log" on each of your script (ticked by default).
Your target -> Build Phases -> expand your script -> the box is here.